# Updating Data Source Login Credentials for SSRS Report Server Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have added a lot of reports with an invalid data source login to an SSRS report sever and I wanted to update the User Name and Password with a script to update it so I don't have to update each report individually.

However, from what I can tell the fields are store as Images and are encrypted. I can't find anything out about how they are encrypted or how to update them. It appears that the User Name and password are stored in the dbo.DataSource tables. Any ideas? I want the script to run in SQL.

Example Login Info:

[image: Report Manager Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be very, very, VERY leery of hacking the Reporting Services tables.  It may be that someone out there can offer a reliable way to do what you suggest, but it strikes me as a good way to clobber your entire installation.

My suggestion would be that you make use of the Reporting Services APIs and write a tiny app to do this for you.  The APIs are very full-featured -- pretty much anything you can do from the Report Manager website, you can do with the APIs -- and fairly simple to use.

The following code does NOT do exactly what you want -- it points the reports to a shared data source -- but it should show you the basics of what you'd need to do.

```
    public void ReassignDataSources()
    {
        using (ReportingService2005 client = new ReportingService2005)
        {
            var reports = client.ListChildren(FolderName, true).Where(ci => ci.Type == ItemTypeEnum.Report);

            foreach (var report in reports)
            {
                SetServerDataSource(client, report.Path);
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetServerDataSource(ReportingService2005 client, string reportPath)
    {
        var itemSources = client.GetItemDataSources(reportPath);
        if (itemSources.Any())
            client.SetItemDataSources(
                reportPath,
                new DataSource[] { 
                        new DataSource() { 
                            Item = CreateServerDataSourceReference(), 
                            Name = itemSources.First().Name 
                        } 
                    });
    }

    private DataSourceDefinitionOrReference CreateServerDataSourceReference()
    {
        return new DataSourceReference() { Reference = _DataSourcePath };
    }
```

Comment: Absolutely right.  Take advantage of some system to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this answers your question directly, but I hope it can offer some assistance.
[MSDN Specifying Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160330.aspx)

MSDN also suggests using shared data sources for this very reason:  See [MSDN on shared data sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156450.aspx#Credentials)